# Configuring node placement and width with TikZ, overlapping nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf

I've created a simple feedback structure but cannot cause the utmost right block not to overlap with the circle. I've tried altering this block's width with `minimum width` and `text width`, but it doesn't do the trick. What do I need to change, to move the block to the right?

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto, node distance=2cm,>=latex']
    \tikzstyle{block} = [draw, rectangle, minimum height=2em, minimum width=3em, text centered, text depth=0pt]
    \tikzstyle{sum} = [draw, circle, node distance=1.5cm]

    \node (input) {};
    \node [above, above of=input] (gyro_input) {};
    \node [block, right of=input] (error) { $\hat{R}^T \bar{R}$ };
    \node [block, right of=error] (normalize) {$P_a(\tilde{R})$};
    \node [block, right of=normalize] (gain) {$C(s)$};
    \node [sum, right of=gain] (sum2) {};
    \node [block, right of=sum2] (correction) {$\dot{\hat{R}} = \hat{R} ( \bar{\Omega}_\times + C(s) P_a (\tilde{R}))$};
    \node [right of=correction] (output) {};
    \node [block, above of=sum2] (R_dynamics) {$\bar{\Omega}_\times$};
    \node [block, below of=error] (transpose) {$\hat{R}^T$};

    \draw [->] (input) node [above] {$\bar{R}$} -- (error);
    \draw [->] (error) -- (normalize) node [midway, above] {$\tilde{R}$};
    \draw [->] (normalize) -- (gain);
    \draw [->] (gain) -- (sum2);
    \draw [->] (sum2) -- (correction);
    \draw [->] (correction) -- node (fork) {} (output) node [above] {$\hat{R}$};
    \draw [->] (gyro_input) node [above] {$\bar{\Omega}$} -- (R_dynamics);
    \draw [->] (R_dynamics) -- (sum2);
    \draw [->] (fork) |- (transpose);
    \draw [->] (transpose) -- (error);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The outcome of the above is:
[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem occurs because the `node distance` is set to 1.5cm. And this distance refers to the distance between node centres, *not* distance between side of nodes. In this case your overlapping node has a width that is far greater than this and thus it will overlap.

You can circumvent it by locally overwriting the `node distance`:

```
\node [block, right of=sum2,node distance=3.5cm]
```

which will do you good.

Another idea which can turn out nice is to explicitly use the nodes anchors to position them. This will yield a consistent distance *between* the side of the nodes. I can't remember if this is implemented in some sort, but it can be done manually like this:

```
\tikzstyle{my below of} = [below=of #1.south]
\tikzstyle{my right of} = [right=of #1.east]
\tikzstyle{my left of} = [left=of #1.west]
\tikzstyle{my above of} = [above=of #1.north]
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto, node distance=.75cm,>=latex']
    \tikzstyle{block} = [draw, rectangle, minimum height=2em, minimum width=3em, text centered, text depth=0pt]
    \tikzstyle{sum} = [draw, circle]

    \node (input) {};
    \node [above, my above of=input] (gyro_input) {};
    \node [block, my right of=input] (error) { $\hat{R}^T \bar{R}$ };
    \node [block, my right of=error] (normalize) {$P_a(\tilde{R})$};
    \node [block, my right of=normalize] (gain) {$C(s)$};
    \node [sum, my right of=gain] (sum2) {};
    \node [block, my right of=sum2] (correction) {$\dot{\hat{R}} = \hat{R} ( \bar{\Omega}_\times + C(s) P_a (\tilde{R}))$};
    \node [my right of=correction] (output) {};
    \node [block,my above of=sum2] (R_dynamics) {$\bar{\Omega}_\times$};
    \node [block,my below of=error] (transpose) {$\hat{R}^T$};

    \draw [->] (input) node [above] {$\bar{R}$} -- (error);
    \draw [->] (error) -- (normalize) node [midway, above] {$\tilde{R}$};
    \draw [->] (normalize) -- (gain);
    \draw [->] (gain) -- (sum2);
    \draw [->] (sum2) -- (correction);
    \draw [->] (correction) -- node (fork) {} (output) node [above] {$\hat{R}$};
    \draw [->] (gyro_input) node [above] {$\bar{\Omega}$} -- (R_dynamics);
    \draw [->] (R_dynamics) -- (sum2);
    \draw [->] (fork) |- (transpose);
    \draw [->] (transpose) -- (error);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Notice that `node distance` now tells you the distance between the node sides and not the node centres. You do need to ensure correct spacing with your positioning of the `gyro_input` node. However, that can easily be done.

On a side note, consider using `\coordinate` for nodes with no text. That will behave more expected as your coordinate `input` will actually have a finite size. And thus the anchors `north/south/east/west` will not be a single point. Try inserting:

```
\draw[blue] (gyro_input.north) -- (gyro_input.south);
```

and see the size of that node. This is due to `inner sep` and `outer sep`.

Comment: Note that you need `\usetikzlibrary{positioning}` for this to work.

Answer (score 2):

With such a regular structure, I prefer to use a `matrix` to place nodes. Values `column sep` and `row sep` represent the distance between node borders but you can fix different values for every column and row. In following example `&[-8mm]` subtracts 8 mm to default column separation between all nodes in first and second column.

A second comment about your code, you can use `coordinate` nodes instead of empty ones.

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,arrows}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[auto, node distance=2cm,>=latex']
    \tikzstyle{block} = [draw, rectangle, minimum height=2em, minimum width=3em, text centered, text depth=0pt]
    \tikzstyle{sum} = [draw, circle, node distance=1.5cm]

\matrix[column sep=1.2cm, row sep=8mm]{
    \coordinate[label=above:$\bar{\Omega}$] (gyro input); &[-8mm] & & &[-7mm] \node [block] (R_dynamics) {$\bar{\Omega}_\times$}; &[-7mm] \\
\coordinate[label=above:$\bar{R}$] (input);
&
\node [block] (error) { $\hat{R}^T \bar{R}$ };
&    
\node [block] (normalize) {$P_a(\tilde{R})$};
&    
\node [block] (gain) {$C(s)$};
&
\node [sum] (sum2) {};
&
\node [block] (correction) {$\dot{\hat{R}} = \hat{R} ( \bar{\Omega}_\times + C(s) P_a (\tilde{R}))$};
&
\coordinate (output) {}; \\
& 
\node [block] (transpose) {$\hat{R}^T$};\\
};

\draw [->] (gyro input) -- (R_dynamics);
\draw [->] (R_dynamics) -- (sum2);

\draw [->] (input)--(error);
\draw[->] (error) -- (normalize) node [midway, above] {$\tilde{R}$};
    \draw [->] (normalize) -- (gain);
    \draw [->] (gain) -- (sum2);
    \draw [->] (sum2) -- (correction);
    \draw [->] (transpose) -- (error);
    \draw [->] (transpose) -| (output)--(correction) node [above,midway] {$\hat{R}$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A solution with [`schemabloc`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/schemabloc) package (see also [Schéma-blocs avec PGF/TIKZ sous LaTeX](http://sciences-indus-cpge.papanicola.info/Schema-blocs-avec-PGF-TIKZ-sous) [French]).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{schemabloc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\sbEntree{input}
\sbBloc[4]{error}{$\hat{R}^T \bar{R}$ }{input} \sbRelier[$\bar{R}$]{input}{error}
\sbBloc[3]{normalize}{$P_a(\tilde{R})$ }{error} \sbRelier[$\tilde{R}$]{error}{normalize}
\sbBlocL{gain}{$C(s)$}{normalize}
\sbCompSum*[5]{sum2}{gain}{ }{ }{ }{ } \sbRelier{gain}{sum2}
\sbBlocL{correction}{$\dot{\hat{R}} = \hat{R} ( \bar{\Omega}_\times + C(s) P_a (\tilde{R}))$}{sum2}
\sbSortie[3]{output}{correction}                
\sbRelier[$\hat{R}$]{correction}{output}
\sbDecaleNoeudy[-6]{input}{gyro input}
\node[above of=gyro input]{$\bar{\Omega}$};
\sbBlocL[20.5]{R_dynamics}{$\bar{\Omega}_\times$}{gyro input} 
\sbDecaleNoeudy[6]{input}{transpose}
\sbBloc[4]{transpose}{$\hat{R}^T$}{transpose}
\sbRelieryx{correction-output}{transpose}
\sbRelier{transpose}{error}
\sbRelier{R_dynamics}{sum2}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: schéma bloc]

Comment: Thanks for the alternate solution. Can anything be done to place `\hat{\Omega}` right above the input bar?

Comment: replace \node[above of=gyro input]{$\bar{\Omega}$};  by
\node[above =0em of gyro input]{$\bar{\Omega}$};</pre>